# Connect DB2 with Java, configuration

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I try to connect from my Java-Application to an existing DB2 Database.
My Code looks like a minimal version of the example shown at [connect DB2 with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530711/connect-db2-with-java).

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Please include Classpath  Where your DB2 Driver is located");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("DB2 driver is loaded successfully");

}
```

When i run this the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

What are the requirements to connect to a DB2?
I added db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_licence_cisuz.jar to the projects build-path and inside the db2jcc.jar exists an DB2Driver.class.

Do I have to configure sth. else?

Comment: How do you execute your app? What's the full stack trace of the exception? is the DB2Driver.class file in `/com/ibm/db2/jcc`?

Comment: Thanks, this was the correct hint: "How do you execute".
My mistake all the time was, that I executed the above code inside an maven-based application.
All I had to do was to add the jar-files to maven repository and not just right-click my project and add to built-path..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in my comment above, I had to add the DB2-Dependency as described at http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

This is because of my project-type: maven-based application. Just adding the jar-files to built-path was not enough. I had to add them to the repo and add it into my pom.xml.